# Signal my main from thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, signals, posix

I'm learning on how to use signals in C with POSIX threads.
I know how to signal threads from main, but how to signal my main from the thread to notify it that it has finished some job? I need the PID of my main. How should I go about doing it?

How can I let my threads know mains PID to send a signal to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the main thread `getpid() == gettid(`), so, you can use `getpid()` or `gettid()` to get PID of main thread.

Comment: Note that this solution is Linux specific and is not portable.